# grails internationalization (i18n)

Tags: variables, grails, groovy, internationalization

i work on grails project

```
def result = "customer"
//(this value is according to returned method parameter, 
//it may be customer, company,... & so on)
def messages = "${message(code: 'default.result.${result}', default:'${result}')}"
```

i need to send a variable inside message code as i mention above

**problem:** this code appears as

```
default.result.${result}
```

that there is no code in message.properties refer to these code

```
there is default.result.customer ....$ so on
```

**Question:** how can i send variable inside message Code?

Comment: 2 answers are correct but i use david answer thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try omitting the double quotes (GString) and it should work like the following:

```
def xxx = "bar"
def m = message(code: "foo.${xxx}", args: ['hello world'])
```

Results in following message-code

```
foo.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
def messages = message(code: 'default.result.' + result, default: result)
```

If you want to pass in some values, e.g. a string, you can define your message like this:

```
default.result.success = Action {0} was successfull.
```

And resolve your code like this:

```
def m = message(code: 'default.result.' + result, args: ['delete User'])
```